# How to enable read_stream in Desktop Server App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

We have an App which is intended to run on a LAN reading a company's own feed and producing local reports with it.

In order to do this I need to enable read_stream but I note that this is not possible without submitting an App for Review.

However in order to do this I need to choose a platform. I am only able to choose between ios/andrioid/Windows App/App on Facebook/Website/Page Tab/XBox/Playstation

A Windows Server is none of these. I looked at Windows App, but this is asking for a Windows Store ID - we do not particularly want to put this in the Windows Store. We just need to turn on read_stream.

Also, I see that the Review Submission requires a minimum of 4 screen shots. This seems a bizarre thing to have to provide for a Windows Service.

Any ideas how I can navigate all this red tape ?

Comment: You can ask any user that have a role on the app for any permission without getting it approved by Facebook

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  The problem we have with this is that this would mean making each of our customers an Admin / Tester / Developer of our App. Which does not seem right.  Are there any other routes available to me?

Comment: Also - is there any Facebook applied time limit on 1) how long one can run with an App which is not made public or submitted for review, 2) How long a user can remain in a tester role ?  In other words is it acceptable to go to market with each of our customers set as a tester?

Comment: You will need to take the app live otherwise no one else will see anything the app does. But you don't need to get the permissions reviewed if you don't plan to ask people that don't have a role on the app for permissions

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.  The App is already "live", my question is really about whether we would be breaking any T&C by going to market indefinitely with users who get their permissions because they have roles on the App.